# OSM Data Extract Streetnames for cities

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

How to extract streetnames with osmosis (Java)?
I have tried to process all Nodes. I put them in a `Map<String, List>` meaning `Map<CityName, ListOfStreetnamesOfThatCity>`:

```
@Override
public void process(EntityContainer entityContainer) {
    if (entityContainer instanceof NodeContainer) {
        final NodeContainer entityContainer1 = (NodeContainer) entityContainer;
        if(containsTagWithKeys(entityContainer1.getEntity().getTags(), "addr:city", "addr:street")) {
            final Map<String, String> tags = entityContainer1.getEntity().getTags()
                                                  .stream()
                                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tag::getKey, Tag::getValue));
            if( cityStreetnames.get(tags.get("addr:city")) == null) {
                    cityStreetnames.put(tags.get("addr:city"), new ArrayList<>());
            }
            String streetname = tags.get("addr:street");
            cityStreetnames.get(tags.get("addr:city")).add(streetname);

        }
    }
}
```

This gives me a subset of all streets per city only. (Not sufficient)

I tried to process all Way nodes

```
if (entityContainer instanceof WayContainer) {
    Way myWay = ((WayContainer) entityContainer).getEntity();

    final Map<String, String> tags = myWay.getTags()
                                             .stream()
                                             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tag::getKey, Tag::getValue));
    if(containsTagWithKeys(myWay.getTags(), "name", "highway") && tags.get("name").length() > 2) {
        names.add(tags.get("name"));
    }
}
```

This gives me a lot of streets but I don't know in which city these ways are located.

I'm really new to OSM data. Is there a way to map a way node to a city? Is there a better way to get all streetnames of a city?

I have used .osm.pbf for Germany from geofabrik.de.

Comment: Maybe you can get some hints via https://help.openstreetmap.org/ by doing a search there for "street list" ?

Comment: I want to extract the data in java with osmosis. Most solutions require to execute command line. Some suggest to import into postgresql. Not really what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Address tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Addresses) are not only present at nodes, they do exist on ways and relations, too. So you need to process all [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) in order to get all `addr:street` and `addr:city` combinations.

In the end this is really a task for a gecoder such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). Your approach will work for many situations but not for all of them. For example some elements will only contain an `addr:street` tag but no `addr:city` tag. A geocoder will be able to resolve the missing city by looking at [administrative boundary relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative), your approach won't.

Comment: Thank you. I already found https://stackoverflow.com/a/24444767/772883 very useful. I'm still looking for a geocoder that works offline.

Comment: Nominatim works offline if you install your own local instance. It requires a postgresql database though.